# Inner div scroll isn't working with firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Inner div scroll isn't working with mozilla firefox browser.

It's working smoothly in chrome.

Is there any hack for firefox scroll? Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6jd25x9/2/

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
#second-fold {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
  width: 100%
}
#second-fold div {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<section id="first-fold">
  <h1>Fold 1</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>

</section>
<section id="second-fold">
  <div>
    <h1>Fold 2</h1>
    <h4>Slide 1</h4>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h4>Slide 2</h4>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h4>Slide 3</h4>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h4>Slide 4</h4>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>

</section>
<section id="third-fold">
  <h1>Fold 3</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Seems the same in both browsers for me?

Comment: Isn't working? By that you mean... "it's not scrolling at all"? or "it's scrolling but is laggy"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second folds' scrollbar to be visible then just set the width less than 70% in the specific jsfiddle example you posted. Other than that everything works fine